# Checking whether post is deleted or saved in edit_post

Tags: custom-post-types

When deleting a custom post type, the function hooked to `edit_post` is fired. How can I check if the post is being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hook is fired after a post is updated. When a post is sended to trash, technically is a `post_status` change, so it's an update and so the hook is fired.

When you want to target post status change better choice are [**post status transitions hooks**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), e.g. to target a post trash use:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'fired_on_post_change_staus', 10, 3 );

function fired_on_post_change_staus( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
   if ( $new_status == 'trash' ) {
        // Do something when post is deleted
   }
}
```

However, when a post is updated, the post status can stay the same, in this case you can use the `edit_post` post hook. Once this hook is fired *after* an update is performed and it pass the post object as second argument you can check the actual post status, e.g.

```
add_action( 'edit_post', 'fired_on_post_edit', 10, 2 );

function fired_on_post_edit( $post_ID, $post ) {
   if ( $post->post_status != 'trash' ) {
        // Do something when post is updated but not deleted
   }
}
```

A more granular control can be reached using **`post_updated`** hook, that is similar to the previous, but pass how post was before the update and how is after, e.g.

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'fired_on_post_edit_2', 10, 3 );

function fired_on_post_edit_2( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
   if ( $post_after->post_status == 'trash' && $post_before->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        // Do something when post is trashed after being published
   }
   if ( $post_after->post_status == 'publish' && $post_before->post_status == 'trash' ) {
        // Do something when post is published after being trash (post undelete)
   }
}
```